# atoi() returning strange value

Tags: c, strtok, atoi

I'm getting some very strange behavior out of the `atoi` command. I am trying to find 2 values out of a range with the format [1:2]
The string being created is done with a dynamic string allocating macro (if Sasprintf throws you)
It will be read in from a file at projects end, however.
Anyway, I seem to be parsing my string correctly, given the correct values of `token` and `token2`. I'm confused, however, why calling `atoi` on `token2` would give me a gibberish answer. Also, I found out in the midst of this that `strtok` is deprecated, I just haven't bothered switching it yet, until I solve this bug.

```
char *token;
char *token2;

int lsb = 0;
int msb = 0;    
char *str = NULL;

Sasprintf(str,"[4:0]");

token = strtok(str,"[");
if(token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(token,":");
    msb = atoi(token);
    printf("%d\n", msb);
    token2 = strtok(NULL,"]");
    puts(token2);

    lsb = atoi(token2);
    printf("%d\n",token2);
}
```

OUTPUT

> 4
>
> 0
>
> 19853443

Comment: `strtok is deprecated`...how?

Comment: My guess is because it's not reentrant

Comment: `printf("%d\n",token2);` should be `printf("%d\n", lsb);`, shouldn't it? Otherwise you're printing out the integer representation of a pointer.

Comment: Since when `strtok` deprecated?

Comment: It's fine for simple programs but causes concurrency issues in threaded applications. Best to use strtok_s

Comment: Paul had it right....really stupid mistake. Thanks for saving me the head pounding. Think I might need to step away from the computer for a bit!

Comment: @SouravGhosh @haccks `man strtok` => `This interface is obsoleted by strsep(3).`

Comment: @SouravGhosh,  I just performed a internet search for the strtok() function as used in C, and did not find any reference indicating that the function is depreciated nor replaced by strsep().  Please post a reference with this information

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to change

```
  printf("%d\n",token2);
```

to

```
  printf("%d\n",lsb);
```

`token2` is a `char *` and you cannot print that using `%d`. Invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

That said, always check the return value of `strtok()` against NULL. Also, [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) is a better alternative to `atoi()`.

Comment: Yup, really stupid mistake. Was looking for something behavioral and i'm just dense instead! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    printf("%d\n",token2);
```

This is not how you print a string, use:

```
    printf("%s\n",token2);
```

or

```
    printf("%d\n", lsb);
```

to print the result of your conversion.